# Firebase auth in webapp without the SDK

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Im trying to implement authentication on my SPA, and it works fine.

The way im doing it is like in the docs:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

const config = {
  // ...
};
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);

// and somewhere else in the code(with all the arguments and stuff)
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword();
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword();
```

Now, my problem is that these imports add too much to the app. I honestly don't think that 180KB(minified, but not compressed) is acceptable for an SPA that aims to work on mobile.

Just for comparison, my whole app, Vuejs + Router + Vuex + other 3~ small libraries and the app logic weight 170KB(minified but not compressed).

So I wanted to know if there is another solution, or if im doing it wrong, or if there is an easy workaround. Ideally, I would be able to just make an HTTP request and get back a JWP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I contacted firebase to add this as a feature request, and they suggested me to use for now the REST API for auth. It requires a custom token, but it is a good solution.

The documentation for the REST API:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the actual endpoints you hit for Firebase auth isn't publicly documented nor have I seen them around the Web. With that said, if you are set on reducing your bundle size, your best bet is to pick apart the SDK and figure out how and what you need to construct.

`signInWithEmailAndPassword` is defined [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/auth/src/auth.js#L1421) and as you can see, it just calls out to another private function and so on.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I got the same conclusions before asking here. But I think it's not a good idea to build my own API, because changes to the internal firebase API might break my code, and other than that, it kinda defeats the purpose of Firebase in my opinion.